# Get inner Object list from MongoDB document with out looping.

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregate, spring-data-mongodb, projection

Suppose I have below model list stored in mongdb.

```
@Document
public class Product {
    private String productName;
    private List<Customer> customers;
}

public class Customer {
    public String firstName;
    List<Address> addresses;  
}

public class Address {
    private String address;
}
```

And I have data like below.

I want to get all addresses related to below query.

```
Query query = new Query();
Criteria product = Criteria.where("productName").is("CHAIR");
Criteria customer = Criteria.where("customers. firstName").is("Ann");
```

I Want to get Address list for upper query with out looping list of customers.

Im using spring data, 
So i want to know how i can do this through MatchOperation, ProjectionOperation, Aggregation or MapReduce with out loop list of customers.

Comment: No aggregation needed. Try `Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("productName").is("CHAIR").and("customers.firstName").is("Ann");
        query.fields().include("productName").elemMatch("customers", Criteria.where("firstName").is("Ann") );` This will output the customer with matching name with address list inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.productDB.aggregate({$match:{"productName":"CHAIR"}},
{$unwind:"$customers"},{$match:{"customers.firstName":"Ann"}},{$project:{
_id:"$productName", address:"$addresses"})
```

please check mongodb aggregation framework for more detailed information